# NodeJS EventEmiter not emiting the event

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

I just wonder if the following code is supposed to work:

```js
// my-class.js

const EventEmmiter = require('events')

class MyClass extends EventEmmiter {
  constructor () {
    super()
  }

  trigger () {
    console.log('trigger')
    this.emit('foo')
  }
}

module.exports = MyClass


// test.js
const MyClass = new (require('./my-class'))

MyClass.trigger()

MyClass.on('foo', () => {
  console.log('event emited')
})

// result: "trigger"
```

As you can see, the even handler `MyClass.on('foo')` doesn't get called. Is there a way to register event listeners outside of the file emitting the event?

Comment: Can you subscribe before you emit the vent?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin they _should_ subscribe before they emit, even. `EventEmitter` is synchronous.

Comment: What you mean by that? I can register a listener inside the `constructor` and it get's called, this I know for sure.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe in that case, you are registering a listener _before_ the event is emitted. In your example code, it's the other way around: you emit, _then_ you subscribe. That's the wrong order.

Comment: @robertklep Oh oh, this make complete sense now. I must have missed this bit of information in the Node documentation.